# Update the content of html

Tags: javascript, html, css

My task is to update the content of html (e.g., change the text, font, color, images).

The tester doesn't know anything about html, so she cannot open the html file herself to change. Each time, she receives feedbacks from the client, she comes back to me and asks me to change (even just a little correction).

Is there any tool that allows to update the content of html in an easy way? This task takes me a lot of time and get me down.

Thanks

Comment: Why the question is bad? This happens in so many companies. This is manual task for so many people.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How easy way you want to update HTML? It will take time if any person does not have knowledge of html and trying to make changes.

Comment: i guess people downvote because tool recommendations are often viewed as not in the scope of StackOverflow. To me it is also unclear what exactly you need: a tool like dreamweaver, that lets you edit the site offline, or a CMS/Wiki implementation were you can alter the content of the site online?

Comment: The tool just allows the user to update the text in html. There is no tool like this for unprofessional people? If so, I will create myself and sell in the market.

Comment: You want like http://4html.net/online-html-editor-text-to-html-converter-853.html ?

Comment: I want a simple tool that can show all the text of a specific html. The tester can use this tool to update the text that she wants without my help in code.

Comment: Why not hire tester who knows his job?

Comment: My company is not an IT company. People almost don't have a background in IT. Looking on code scares them.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case, it would be better to use a content management system like WordPress, so then the site can be updated without needing to know HTML.